# How can I create mappings for replace mode?

Tags: key-bindings, replace

I know how to create key mappings in normal mode using `nmap` and in insert mode using `imap`. However I do not know how to create mappings in replace mode. I would assume it's either `rmap` or `Rmap`, but both of these commands are invalid. Which command can I use to create mappings in replace mode in vim?

Comment: According to the [map section in the Vim Reference Manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html), there is not a Replace Mode. What are you trying to replace in Normal Mode?

Comment: Not sure how much it would help but this question was asked previously: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/796462/remap-keys-in-replace-mode-in-vim)

Comment: By replace mode I am referring to the mode after you type 'R' in normal mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has no `rmap`, replace mode map is created  in `imap` with a mode test:

```
inoremap <expr> <a-k> mode() ==# 'R' ? 'replace' : 'insert'
```

`:h mode()` is transient, you must test it in `:h map-expr`.

Note it won't work for `r`.

Comment: What is this command supposed to do? Sorry I do not know very much vimscript.

Comment: @coder54321 It output `replace` or `insert` based on your current mode.  The `:h ...` is valid ex command, you can execute it in vim to get help.